# Asp net - Delete record from db using OnDelete()

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Trying to create simple CRUD app using Asp Net Core. I have 2 entities:
Department and Employee( one to many ). I need to delete record from Department table. But when Im trying to delete record using `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` or `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)` i have exception:

> UPDATE or DELETE in table"Departments" violates foreign key constraint
>   "FK_Employees_Departments_DepartmentCode" table"Employees"

How can i fix this problem ?
Entity Employee:

```
public class Employee
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Input fullname of employee")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Input date of birth")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Input code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Input fullname of employee")]
        public int Salary { get; set; }

        public string DepartmentCode { get; set; } 
        public Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

Entity Department:

```
public class Department
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Input name of department")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Input code of department")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public Department()
        {
            Employees = new List<Employee>();
        }
    }
```

Context class settings:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)

{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasMany<Employee>(d => d.Employees)
            .WithOne(e => e.Department)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.DepartmentCode)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasKey(d => d.Code);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasKey(e => e.Code);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasIndex(d => d.Name).IsUnique();
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to delete an employee(s) if you delete a department(s)? I would introduce a new table to your schema. An EmployeeDepartment table. That would be a better design IMO.

Comment: No, i want to delete department without cascade deleting of empoyees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of all fields in the [`DeleteBehavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-3.0) enum only two actually add cascaded foreign key behavior to the database: `Cascade` and `SetNull`. All other options create foreign keys with no action on delete, but differ in what EF will do to its tracked entities.

In your case it should probably be `SetNull` because I assume that Employees can exist without Department. This setting will allow you to delete a `Department` object without loading its `Employees`. The database will set their `DepartmentCode` to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The delete behavior configured in EF can only be applied tho Entities that are tracked by EF change tracking. So you would need to load all Employees that belong to the department to make this work as expected.

BUT The database foreign key definition also defines the on delete action (cascading, set null, do nothing) So even if you code within your context a set null strategy, the DB still might apply different strategy for on delete. EF core defaults to cascade delete.

Comment: So, if i want to delete record in department table, I need to load all employees that belong to department and set department value to null ? Like that ?               
          foreach(var e in repo.Employees.ToList())
            {
                if(e.DepartmentId == department.Id)
                {
                    e.DepartmentId = null;
                }
                continue;
            }
            repo.Departments.Remove(department);
            repo.SaveChanges();

Comment: No - you need to have a look at your database schema to see how foreign key is configured. Maybe you need to adjust it, maybe you can't, maybe you don't need to change anything. Then you set up EF accordingly. Maybe the foreign key in the database is configured to not allow nulls then you cannot set null in EF or you will get errors when saving. If nulls are allowed in the db you can load the department including the employees, then delete the department and EF will do the right thing automatically. If your foreign key in the DB is configured to set nulls, you can just delete the Department

Comment: How you delete depends on your setup which we don't know